# Lightning Message - what is the purpose of LightningMessageFields?

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am currently learning communication between components using [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation).

The Lightning Message is defined in a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningMessageChannel xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <masterLabel>SampleChannel</masterLabel>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <description>This is a sample Lightning Message Channel.</description>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>variable1</fieldName>
        <description>Variable 1</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
    <lightningMessageFields>
        <fieldName>variable2</fieldName>
        <description>Variable 2</description>
    </lightningMessageFields>
</LightningMessageChannel>
```

What is the point of the LightningMessageFields tag, if the subscribe service works in a way that you create the message yourself without using the LightningMessageFields?

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { publish, MessageContext } from 'lightning/messageService';
import SOME_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/testChannel__c';

export default class MessageChannelPublish extends LightningElement {
    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

    publishTrue() {
        const payload = { data: true};
        publish(this.messageContext, SOME_MESSAGE, payload);
    }

    publishFalse() {
        const payload = {data: false};
        publish(this.messageContext, SOME_MESSAGE, payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess, at the very least so tooling can show information (names and descriptions) to assist the developer.

Comment: Do you mean Tooling API? Or when viewing/editing the component itself?

Comment: Tooling is software that you use to do stuff. This may well use the Tooling API. An example of Tooling is the VSCode Salesforce IDE.